# Cannot Parse a Xmlement with Xpath Correctly

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

i have web service that returns a xmlement like below

```
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Type>C</Type>
   <AppDate>2012-05-01T00:00:00</AppDate>
   <Applicants>
      <ID>1234</ID>
   </Applicants>
   <Applicants>
      <ID>0</ID>
   </Applicants>
   <Status>O</Status>
</Application>
```

on my client side 
i have a code like this

```
XmlElement root = proxy.CallWebservice();

XmlNodeList nodeList;
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/Application/Applicants");
foreach (XmlNode applicants in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(applicants.InnerXml);
}
```

PROBLEM: i cannot get anything to output.

BUT

if i do this

```
File.WriteAllText(@"d:\output.xml", root.OuterXml.ToString());
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"d:\output.xml");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

XmlNodeList nodeList;
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/Application/Applicants");
foreach (XmlNode title in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(title.InnerXml);
}
```

IT WORKS, i do not want to have to write to the file to just read the nodes. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I just wonder if it's because you're loading the file into an XmlDocument whereas you are only ever using an XmlElement for the non-working sample.

Comment: XPath problems are usually about namespaces. If namespaces are "off" things work, but if they are "on" they fail until you register the namespace with the xml processor.

Can you try removing the 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' attribute - that will provide a clue.

Comment: A guess but I suspect Proxy.WebService and Document.DocumentElement aren't the same node, quick debug should tell you.

Answer (score 0):

i had to use 
XmlNodeList nodeList;

```
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("Applicants");
```

as my root was application